# How to get a list of restricted_components with it's related information?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables structure (DDL):

```
CREATE TABLE restricted_components
(
    component_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    resources_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    component_dom_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    component_dom_class VARCHAR(50),
    component_dom_data_name VARCHAR(50),
    visible TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE resources
(
    resources_id INT(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    resources_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    menu_href VARCHAR(128),
    menu_text VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE acl_groups_to_resources
(
    groups_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    resources_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    bitmask SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PRIMARY` PRIMARY KEY (groups_id, resources_id)
);

CREATE TABLE groups
(
    groups_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    groups_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I am trying to get a list of `restricted_components` with it's related information from the rest of the tables meaning the `resources_name` and `groups_name`.

I have made this query:

```
SELECT
  `rc`.*,
  `rs`.resources_name,
  `gr`.`groups_name`
FROM `restricted_components` AS `rc`
  LEFT JOIN `resources` AS `rs` ON rc.resources_id = rs.resources_id
  LEFT JOIN `acl_groups_to_resources` AS `acl_gr` ON rs.resources_id = acl_gr.resources_id
  LEFT JOIN `groups` AS `gr` ON acl_gr.groups_id = gr.groups_id
```

But is wrong since I have unwanted results as the image below shown:

[image]

I am sure the problem is on the `LEFT JOIN` but I can't find where exactly and how to fix this.

**Update #1:** Using `JOIN` instead doesn't work either.

[image]

I believe the problem is in the data but I am not sure at all, hopefully someone will have a time to check this.

Can I get any help?

> Note: I have leave a set of data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lc99k1dks0bnxqn/data.tar.gz?dl=0) so you can play with it if needed but is not accurate, you'll need to remove some columns and it's values.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` gives all the rows in the `right` table, even the missing ones.  You probably want `JOIN`.

Comment: @RickJames see my update :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with LEFT + INNER You can change logic of SQL query

If You need all from **restricted_component** - LEFT JOIN
But because groups must be for all - INNER

```
SELECT
  `rc`.*,
  `rs`.resources_name,
  `gr`.`groups_name`
FROM `restricted_components` AS `rc`
  LEFT JOIN `resources` AS `rs` ON rc.resources_id = rs.resources_id
  INNER JOIN `acl_groups_to_resources` AS `acl_gr` ON rs.resources_id = acl_gr.resources_id
  INNER JOIN `groups` AS `gr` ON acl_gr.groups_id = gr.groups_id
ORDER BY component_id
```

result from Your dataset

```
1   1   button_1    button_1        1   Users   Administrators
1   1   button_1    button_1        1   Users   User Admins
2   2   button_2            0   Companies   Administrators
3   3   button_3            0   Hardware    Administrators
4   4   button_4            0   Reports Administrators
4   4   button_4            0   Reports Reports Admin
5   5   button_5            0   Notifications   Administrators
5   5   button_5            0   Notifications   Company Admins
```

Comment: I believe this is what I am looking for. I need to play a bit with it, I'll accept the answer for now but will come back if anything else comes up, thx

Comment: it always - non stoping game :) clarifying requirements You will update logic, but general logic must be non-sql - what we must have all, what only if found + any other conditions explained by normal words, than will be easy to convert all this to SQL